# How to filter a dataframe by multiple columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem as below:

I have two dataframes

Dataframe DF1:

```
ID, Name, age
1   name1  18
2   name2  20
```

DataFrame DF2:

```
ID, Name, age
1   name1 18
3   name3 19
```

I am attempting to filter DF2 to exclude records contained in DF1 by ID and Name so that I can get new DF2 like

```
ID, Name, age
3   name3  19
```

and then union these two dataframes to get final result:

```
ID, Name, age
1   name1  18
2   name2  20
3   name3  19
```

To do this in T-SQL, I can write a statement like

```sql
INSERT INTO DF1 
SELECT ID, Name, age FROM DF2 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM DF1 WHERE DF1.ID = DF2.ID AND DF1.Name = DF2.Name)
```

But I find that "insert" is not supported in dataframe in sparkSQL.
So my questions are:

How can I filter a dataframe based on multiple column?

How can I union two dataframes together?
I am appreciate for any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UNION followed by DISTINCT

Assuming that the records are unique the simplest way to achieve what you want is to take `UNION` and follow it by `DISTINCT`:

```
val df1 = Seq((1, "name1", 18), (2, "name2", 20)).toDF("ID", "Name", "age")
val df2 = Seq((1, "name1", 18), (3, "name3", 19)).toDF("ID", "Name", "age")

df1.unionAll(df2).distinct.show

// +---+-----+---+
// | ID| Name|age|
// +---+-----+---+
// |  1|name1| 18|
// |  2|name2| 20|
// |  3|name3| 19|
// +---+-----+---+
```

**Characteristics**:

- has to access `df1` only once
- shuffles both `df1` and `df2` independent of the size

#### EXCEPT followed by UNION

Another approach is to use `EXCEPT` followed by `UNION`:

```
df1.unionAll(df2.except(df1)).show  // df2.distinct.except to drop duplicates

// +---+-----+---+
// | ID| Name|age|
// +---+-----+---+
// |  1|name1| 18|
// |  2|name2| 20|
// |  3|name3| 19|
// +---+-----+---+
```

**Properties**:

- has to access `df1` twice
- shuffles both frames independent of the size (?)
- can be used with three frames (`df3.unionAll(df2.except(df1))`)

#### LEFT OUTER JOIN followed by SELECT with filter followed by UNION

Finally if you want only partial match `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with filter followed by `UNION` should do the trick:

```
df2.as("df2")
  .join(
    df1.select("id", "name").as("df1"),
    // join on id and name
    $"df1.id" === $"df2.id" && $"df1.name" === $"df2.name",
    "leftouter")
  // This could be replaced by .na.drop(...)
  .where($"df1.id".isNull && $"df1.Name".isNull)
  .select($"df2.id", $"df2.name", $"df2.age")
  .unionAll(df1)
  .show

// ---+-----+---+
// | ID| Name|Age|
// +---+-----+---+
// |  3|name3| 19|
// |  1|name1| 18|
// |  2|name2| 20|
// +---+-----+---+
```

**Properties**:

- has to access `df1` twice
- if one the data frames is small enough to broadcasted it may not require shuflle
- can be used with three data frames

Comment: Having seen the different solutions I wonder about their performance. Which solution is the best performance-wise and why?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I've been thinking about it myself and there are different trade-offs involved. Assuming that we use only 2 frames and both are large I would go with the first approach because it has to access `df1` only once (there is no branch and merge). If there 3 frames involved (we merge with different frame than we subtract) then this is simply not applicable. Join based solution would be preferable if one of the frames is small enough to be broadcasted to avoid shuffle.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Truth be told I am not sure about `except`. It looks like it cannot use broadcasting so I would use it only as an alternative to the first solution when you want to merge with third frame.

Comment: Any idea how to measure it? I'd start with web UI and a `SparkListener`, but perhaps there are more pro tools/ways?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski UI for simple cases, and Docker + Munin to measure impact on complete pipeline are usually good enough for me. One problem is that there are to many moving parts to measure things like this in isolation.